# Cookbook @recipe_files not found when using recipe and single file

Tags: chef-infra, chef-recipe, chef-solo

When I combine using a cookbook recipe and a single, non-recipe file using chef-client 12.5 on Windows, I get the error

> Cookbook @recipe_files not found. If you're loading @recipe_files from
>   another cookbook, make sure you configure the dependency in your
>   metadata

For, example, my command line is

```
chef-client -r mycookbook::default /individual_recipes/my_non_cookbook_recipe.rb
```

Running

```
chef-client -r mycookbook::default
```

or

```
chef-client /individual_recipes/my_non_cookbook_recipe.rb
```

works though. Is there a way to get the single command line to work? I don't want to create a whole separate cookbook for this single recipe file.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ability to run single files is kind of an accident. We added `chef-apply` to make it more official and should probably deprecate it in `chef-client`. In neither case does it support this though.

Comment: is there any way to pass an "extra" cookbook path to use to chef-client command line? That way we could continue with the approach of a single very small recipe?

Comment: No, other than hand-editing the cache files and use the footgun option to disable cache sync.

Comment: All cookbooks for chef-client are managed via Chef Server, it's kind of the whole point :)

Comment: running here in local mode

Comment: Stop using local mode, use chef-solo. And in that case just dump the local recipe in the cookbooks path and run it via `-r` or whatever else you use for tracking run lists.

Comment: The ability to run single file recipes isn't really 'accidental' and it was deliberately added to the client-client command line especially to support some chef-provisioning use cases.  However, we've never supported this much mix-and-match and most likely we'd just raise and tell you to pick a model and stick with it.  You should write a cookbook to wrap the new recipe.  You have to create a few extra subdirs and a metadata.rb and that's it.

Comment: local mode was a transitional thing until we fixed chef-solo. This has now been finished and you can go back to solo as per normal.

Comment: I see. Is there some documentation on the key differences between solo and zero?

Comment: No, the only difference is the value of `Chef::Config[:solo]`. All the same impl under the hood now.